# Log an AWS APIGateway proxy transformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, aws-api-gateway

We have a lambda sitting inside of a private security group which needs to make a call to an outside API across the internet. To do this we decided to go with a proxy REST API that will allow the lambda to call the endpoint using an internal AWS address like this:

```
https://<myapigatewayid>.execute-api.<my-region>.amazonaws.com/<myname>/<my-proxy-call-path>/?arg1=123&arg2=345
```

The proxy integration looks like this:

```
    MyAPIGetProxyMethod:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
      Properties:
        ResourceId: !Ref MyAPIGetProxyResource
        RestApiId: !Ref Proxy
        AuthorizationType: NONE
        HttpMethod: GET
        RequestParameters:
          method.request.querystring.arg1: true
          method.request.querystring.arg2: true
        Integration:
          IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
          Type: HTTP_PROXY
          RequestParameters:
            integration.request.header.Authorization: "'Bearer <my-bearer-token>'"
            integration.request.querystring.arg1: method.request.querystring.arg1
            integration.request.querystring.arg2: method.request.querystring.arg2
          Uri: https://some.api.com/reports/
```

**We want to log the actual transformed URL that is being called in order to see if the format is correct. Ie something like this:**

```
https://some.api.com/reports/?arg1=123&arg2=345
```

Q: does anyone know how to configure the APIGateway log for the API so that it will log the transformed URL?  Currently our log format looks like this:

```
requestId: $context.requestId, ip: $context.identity.sourceIp, caller: $context.identity.caller, user: $context.identity.user, contextPath: $context.path, contextOverRidePath: $context.requestOverride.path.path_name, requestTime: $context.requestTime, httpMethod: $context.httpMethod, resourcePath: $context.resourcePath, status: $context.status, protocol: $context.protocol, responseLength: $context.responseLength
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update on this. The needed logs were apparently available to us the whole time, just not where we expected.

We had been looking at the CloudWatch log group configured for the API-Gateway REST API proxying our calls. While there were logs in there they did not contain the transformed URI we wanted to see. Instead we found them in another log group that API Gateway seems to configure automatically named `API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_<api-id>/<stage>`. In this log group we found the transformed URI we needed. It looked like this:

```
(ea182623-ac18-49bb-a6d4-95bee66a5039) Endpoint request URI: https://some.api.com/reports/?arg1=123&arg2=345
```

I do believe that Quassnoi's answer is also correct in that you still need full request and response logs configured for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Full Request and Response Logs in your stage properties (or override them for an individual method).

In CloudFormation, it's done by setting [`AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment/MethodSetting/LoggingLevel`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-deployment-methodsetting.html#cfn-apigateway-deployment-methodsetting-logginglevel) to `INFO`

Make sure that you also have [`DataTraceEnabled`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-deployment-methodsetting.html#cfn-apigateway-deployment-methodsetting-datatraceenabled) set to `ON`

Comment: Hi and thanks for the feedback. Yes we already had these params set on our stage deployment. Unfortunately that does not really resolve the issue which is how can we print out the transformed URL that is ultimately being called.